# magento2 megamenu cannot save after I modify the database

Tags: magento2, megamenu

I am working with the magento2 ves magemenu. I create a magemenu in my local environment, and after that I migrate the tables which related to ves magemenu to the integration environment.

[image]

But when I use the admin of remote integration environment, I cannot save the new edit of the menu.

Is there any problem with the operation?

Comment: Can you presise more the error you had !

Comment: There is no error information show in the webpage. It just has no reaction when I click the save button. So, I have no idea what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is still existed. But if I click **preview** firstly
[buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBMXM.jpg)

Then if I click save, it can be saved.